# Bootstrap which style controls the hover style for an active parent menu item

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing a dropdown menu in Bootstrap and I want to know which style enables the active background style(highlighted) to remain active while the cursor is hovering on its child item.

The code uses bootstraps default classes.

It's driving me nuts trying to find it!

I found a jsfiddle done by @Andres Ilich, it shows bootstrap with a `multi level dropdown`
http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/2858/

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gets the specific styling for that from the CSS Below:

```
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a {}
```

You can change the styling for this by using the same selector and updating the styles.

For example:

```
.dropdown-submenu:hover>a {
    background: red;
}
```

[image: Twitter Bootstrap Submenu Hover Style]

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/x2XVt/3/

Comment: Thanks @N1ck you saved me from a breakdown. Cheers